# PLY Store complete function block

Tags: python, ply

I want to parse some C files and extract all information about the defined functions (parameter list, function block and function type).
In my approach I tried to save the parameter list and the function block in specific lex token.
For that I used a conditional lexer. The approach for the parameter list is quite easy I guess. I started the conditional state everytime I found a left parenthesis. Then I count all additional opening parenthesis and closing parenthesis. If this counter hits zero again, i take position of first opening parenthesis and position of last opening parenthesis and store the information in specific lex token.

```
def t_parameter_rparen(t):
r'\)'
t.lexer.paren_level -= 1

if t.lexer.paren_level == 0:
    t.value = t.lexer.lexdata[t.lexer.parameter_start:t.lexer.lexpos - 1]
    t.type = 'PARAMETERLIST'
    t.lexer.begin('INITIAL')
    return t
```

I chose the same procedure for the function block condition but here comes my problem:

In one of my C code files there are some preprocessor directives which really mess up code structure.
An example:

```
#ifdef SECURITY_STORAGE_MANAGER
#ifdef FALLBACK_MODE

void DecodeFile(uint8* Address, uint32 Length, bool zeroize)

#else

void DecodeFile(uint8* Address, uint32 Length)

#endif
{
uint32 Crc = 0;
uint8* Buffer = Address

#else

#ifdef FALLBACK_MODE
void DecodeFile(bool zeroize)

#else

void DecodeFile(void)
#endif
{
uint32 Crc = 0;
uint8* Buffer = Address
#endif

here starts the (common) function block

}
```

This example shows, that there is an uneven number of left braces to right braces.
As I start the specific condition and wait for an even number of braces I run into an EOF problem.
I can never stop the condition and save the content of this brace construct so I run into everything being an error token.
Next problem is that if I want to parse another file after that my lexer is still broken.
I will provide my code example after that.

As far as I know there is no option to handle preprocessor directives with this lexer (otherwise I maybe need to look ahead and determine whether its an used define or not and regarding to that maybe just skip the content of this #ifdef.
On the other hand I have no idea how to handle a complete function block with yacc.
Maybe someone of you has an idea how I could solve this problem.

```
import ply.lex as lex
import ply.yacc as yacc

states = (
    ('function', 'exclusive'),
    ('parameter', 'exclusive'),
)

reserved = {
    'void': 'VOID',
    'int': 'INT',
    'uint8': 'UINT8',
    'uint16': 'UINT16',
    'bool': 'BOOL',
}

tokens = [
    'STRING',
    'LBRACE',
    'RBRACE',
    'LPAREN',
    'RPAREN',
    'SEMICOLON',
    'NUMERIC',
    'LBRACKET',
    'RBRACKET',
    'PARAMETERLIST',
    'ARGUMENTS',
] + list(reserved.values())

t_ignore = '\\ \t-."§$%&!=,*:+<>|?\';[]_-,;#!'
t_parameter_ignore = '\\ \t#/-."§$%&!=,*:+<>|?\'[];_-#!'
t_function_ignore = '\\ \t#/-."§$%&!=,*:+<>|?\'();_-,[]'

# Start of token description for INITIAL state

t_LBRACE = r'\{'
t_RBRACE = r'\}'
t_LPAREN = r'\('
t_RPAREN = r'\)'

# def t_HASH(t):
#     r'\#'
#     pass


def t_STRING(t):
    r'[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z_0-9]*'
    t.type = reserved.get(t.value, 'STRING')
    return t


def t_NUMERIC(t):
    r'\d+'
    return t


# Start of token description for parameter list lexing state


def t_parameter(t):
    r'\('
    t.lexer.parameter_list_start = t.lexer.lexpos
    t.lexer.paren_level = 1
    t.lexer.push_state('parameter')


def t_parameter_lparen(t):
    r'\('
    t.lexer.paren_level += 1


def t_parameter_rparen(t):
    r'\)'
    t.lexer.paren_level -= 1

    if t.lexer.paren_level == 0:
        t.value = t.lexer.lexdata[t.lexer.parameter_list_start:t.lexer.lexpos - 1]
        t.type = 'PARAMETERLIST'
        t.lexer.pop_state()
        return t


def t_parameter_STRING(t):
    r'[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z_0-9]*'
    t.type = 'STRING'
    pass


def t_parameter_NUMERIC(t):
    r'\d+'
    t.type = 'NUMERIC'
    pass


# Start of token description for function block lexing state


def t_function(t):
    r'\{'
    t.lexer.function_block_start = t.lexer.lexpos
    t.lexer.brace_level = 1
    t.lexer.push_state('function')


def t_function_lbrace(t):
    r'\{'
    t.lexer.brace_level += 1


def t_function_rbrace(t):
    r'\}'
    t.lexer.brace_level -= 1

    if t.lexer.brace_level == 0:
        t.value = t.lexer.lexdata[t.lexer.function_block_start:t.lexer.lexpos - 1]
        t.type = 'FUNCTIONBLOCK'
        t.lexer.pop_state()
        return t


def t_function_STRING(t):
    r'[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z_0-9]*'
    t.type = 'STRING'
    return t


def t_function_NUMERIC(t):
    r'\d+'
    t.type = 'NUMERIC'
    pass


# Start of token description valid for all states


def t_ANY_newline(t):
    r'\n+'
    t.lexer.lineno += len(t.value)


def t_ANY_error(t):
    print("Illegal character '%s'" % t.value[0])
    t.lexer.skip(1)


def t_ANY_comment(t):
    r'(/\*(.|\n)*?\*/)|(//.*)'
    pass


def t_ANY_ignore_comments(t):
    r'//.*'
    pass


lexer = lex.lex()

test_string = '''
#ifdef SECURITY_STORAGE_MANAGER
#ifdef FALLBACK_MODE
void DecodeFile(uint8* Address, uint32 Length, bool zeroize)
#else
void DecodeFile(uint8* Address, uint32 Length)
#endif
{
uint32 Crc = 0;
uint8* Buffer = Address
#else
#ifdef FALLBACK_MODE
void DecodeFile(bool zeroize)
#else
void DecodeFile(void)
#endif
{
uint32 Crc = 0;
uint8* Buffer = Address
#endif
here starts the (common) function block
}
'''

lexer.input(test_string)

for tok in lexer:
    print(tok)
```

Comment: Perhaps you need to pass your file through the preprocessor before trying to analyse it. Handling preprocessor conditionals is pretty complicated in the general case.

Comment: something like cpp filename.c > filename.preprocessed ?
Never tried it before but I will think of it

Comment: If you don't want to fully preprocess, you could check out "unifdef" and its successors. The one I usually use is [coan](https://github.com/dbremner/coan2) but there might be something more recent, too.

Comment: do they support the full range of preprocessor directives? I found the full range of variations in my code files (ifdef if defined ifndef if !defined and so on)
Seems like this only support the common ones

Comment: Yes, it's quite complete. It doesn't expand macros (except in preprocessor conditionals)  nor does it attempt to handle #include directives, but it can handle any conditional, including complex expressions.

Answer (score 0):

Okay I have chosen gcc to preprocess my code files.
The command i use:
`gcc -save-temps -E -c -o <outputfile.i> <inputfile.c>`

Before that I create a copy of the original files where I delete all #includes so I won't have to worry about providing all libs and so on.

Now everything seems to work really well.